# Laravel/Eloquent relation using id value combination of 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

The simplified info: I have a database where I have a table with columns 'code1' and 'code2', these are used to make an id for another table where the id column is 'code1.code2'. The columns are varchar columns.

Full info: If you are wondering I am working on an importer for geonames database and the geonames table has country_code and admin1_codes and they have another table called admin1_codes and that table has an ID column of country_code.admin1_code (concataneted with dot). If you need further info about geonames database, it is freely available at their web site.

So I want to make a relation using eloquent models but it seems impossible. I am thinking that I need to make my own custom db relation class for this.

So the question is, what would be the best way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I came up with a workaround using a scope:

```
$query = $query->leftJoin('table2',function($join) {
    $join->on(
        DB::raw('table2.code = CONCAT_WS(\'.\','.
                'table1.code1,'.
                'table1.code2)'),
        DB::raw(''),
        DB::raw('')
   );
});
return $query;
```

This successfully joins the relevant row while matching the codes. However I would like to setup a relation between tables. Any ideas on if this is even possible using Eloquent? or can you think about a more elegant solution?

Comment: If you have found a solution, I would be very interested!

Comment: I can't remember anymore what I did with this :) You could check my repository at github yurtesen/geonames to see the code...